# How to prove the function $b : \mathbb Z × \mathbb Z → \mathbb Z$ defined by $b(m, n) = 3m + n$ is surjective?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

> How to prove the function $b : \mathbb Z × \mathbb Z → \mathbb Z$ defined by $b(m, n) = 3m + n$ is surjective?

I believe it is surjective and I can explain it using words but not proof talk. Give me any integer in the codomain, I can always input $m$ as $0$ and $n$ to be that integer to output that integer.

Any tips on how to prove it? Correct me if my reasoning is incorrect.

I tend to struggle with proving a function is surjective much more than injective since I usually prove the contra positive.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The function $b$ is surjective since any element $n$ of its codomain is in its image: $n=b(0,n)$.

Comment: Or $m =b\left(\frac m 3,0\right)$. :)

Comment: @zkutch That only works if $m$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: joke ruined @azif00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a more general solution (and to show that it wouldn't work for example with the function $b(m,n)=3m+6n$), the GCD of two integers is the smallest positive linear combination of them. Since the gcd of $3$ and $1$ (the coefficients of $m,n$) is $1$, there will be integers $m_0,n_0$ such that $3m_0+n_0=1$.

Then for any $k\in\mathbb Z$, $b(km_0,kn_0)=k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take any number in $\mathbb{Z}$, say $k$, and divide it by $3$, then $k=3q+r$, where $r$ is the reminder of the division. So, it shows the surjectivity of the function.

Comment: is this wrong? I saw a down vote

Comment: This method is not wrong, but more convoluted than just taking $(0, n)$ as OP mentioned.

Comment: So, is it a reason to obtain a downvote? I do not think so. If, for you, the answer is much more long way, do not upvote.  Moreover, I understand that the surjectivity is given just going by pair $(0,n)$. However, the idea of this type of exercise relates to divisibility. I do not want to get upvotes or to be the selected answer, I only want to show another solution.